# Kubernetes custom HPA on top of cloud watch collected metrics, how to interpret the output?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-hpa

I am running a scaling policy that depends on the average number of items in the SQS queue.
Here is the sample output of
`kubectl get hpa -w`

```
"aws_sqs_approximate_number_of_messages_visible_average" on Service/generation-service (target average value):  22834m / 4
```

What is this value `22834m`, what does it mean?

Comment: The output provides an interface to view and analyze metrics from your  SQS queue. **The 22834 number of messages available for retrieval from the queue**.

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Your answer is incorrect as it means: 22.834. m stands for millis.